# JQuery with Eel: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Tags: javascript, python, html, jquery

I'm learning Python and JS. I tried to write an application which shows the weather. But I got this error:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
main.html:27 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: eel is not defined
    at display_weather (main.html:27)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (main.html:32)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

I've tried a lot of stuff to solve the problem, but I can't. There is a problem with eel, already I've installed eel which has shown in tutorial.This is file with html and js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Weather by Alibek</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="/eel.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="image/png" href="weather-icon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <input id="location" type="text" placeholder="Write the name of your Country ot City" required="" value="Bukhara, Uzbekistan">

    <button id ="show">Know the weather</button>

    <div id="info ">
        
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        async function display_weather(){
            let place = document.getElementById('location').value;

            let res = await eel.get_weather(place)();
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = res;
        }

        jQuery('#show').on('click', function(){
            display_weather();
        });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

And here is python code:

```
import eel
import pyowm


own = pyowm.OWM('d845c8640738fe82515cb1277bb3dd38')

@eel.expose
def get_weather(place):

    mgr = own.weather_manager()

    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(city)
    w = observation.weather 

    temp = w.temperature('celsius')['temp']

    return city + ' ' +  str(temp)

#eel.init('web')
#eel.start('index.html', size=(700, 700))
```

Some people say that I have to upload the eel file with these files, but where I should get that file? Some of them say I should download it, but I have already downloaded it through cmd. By the way I use Linux Mint 20.

Comment: Why do you comment the last two lines which are required in the Python file? Also change `place` to `city` in the line `def get_weather(place)`.  In `index.html`, `<div id="info ">` should be `<div id="info">`.

Comment: Because that was shown in video, I did the exact same thing. Also tried to write these two lines which commented now, I did not work. I did what you suggested, it didn't work. The same error

Comment: I have tested your code (with my fix suggestions) and it works fine.

Comment: Did you open the `index.html` file directly in the browser? If yes, then it will have the mentioned error.

Comment: Yes, I can not open it in different way, until I have the error I can't run it through cmd. I did it what you said, but it did not help me, the error has not disappeared. Some say that I should run it through server, I am looking for how to do it.

Comment: You should execute the Python script instead of opening the `index.html` directly in a browser.

Comment: See the [result](https://imgur.com/8pGJ71s).